# Why the parsec (pc) is still a good cosmological definition in the curved spacetime in a large scale of universe?

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, curvature, units, distance

The parsec (pc) is a unit of length used to measure the large distances to astronomical objects outside the Solar System, approximately equal to 3.26 light-years or 206,000 astronomical units (au), i.e. 30.9 trillion kilometres (19.2 trillion miles).

The definition can be understood from this figure below.

### question

However, because the universe should be a curved spacetime instead of a flat spacetime, why the use of the 1 arc second measurement: $$\text{1 arc second = 1 AU / 1 pc}$$ is still a good cosmological definition? Should we include the possible global property of the curvature in the universe into account?

I mean why not taking into account of hyperbolic or differential geometry in the definition to make the "distance unit" has a curvature dependence?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

*Space* is not curved. Space is flat, within observational measurements. *Spacetime* is curved. Big difference.  There's some subtlety here, and I'm not the best expert to tell you about it in depth, but one example of the difference:
If you measure the distance between two points far apart in space:

$r^2=x^2+y^2+z^2$ will hold true, for a given Cartesian Coordinate system you impose, and the coordinate distances are $(x,y,z)$

Now, for two *events* far apart in spacetime (say, a distant supernova emitting light, and that light reaching Earth)

$s^2=-(ct)^2+x^2+y^2+z^2$

will NOT hold true (as it would on a flat spacetime). $(x,y,z)$ are the coordinate distances as before, and $t$ is the time interval between the events.  [all these measurements according to some single observer].

So for measuring distances in space, at least globally in general, the Cartesian rules of geometry are the correct tools